# Arbitrage pricing models

Tags: interest-rates, arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory, heath-jarrow-morton

I have been reading Wu's Interest rate modeling and in his chapter on the HJM model he says that

> With arbitrage pricing models, the prices of the basic instruments are treated as model inputs rather than as outputs, so their prices are naturally reproduced.

This sentence sounds interesting but I cannot make sense of this. Does anyone have a good explanation? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some more context? Seems similar to calibration where you calibrate model on vanilla payoffs.